# Vite @ aliase not working for a Vue image src

Tags: javascript, vue.js, alias, vite

The goal is to display an image using view but the images fail to load:
[Spots where image fails to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjnOF.png)

When using the developer console the src shows as `/~/assets/user.png`

The alias works when importing the Vue components but does not work for the image src.

This is the vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { join } from 'path'
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '/~': join(__dirname, 'src'),
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        Vue(),
        Pages({
            extensions: ['vue'],
        }),
    ],
    ssgOptions: {
        script: 'async',
        formatting: 'minify',
    },
})
```

This is one of the Vue files:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex">
        <span class="flex flex-col">
            <span class="font-extralight text-sm">Thursday, 1st July</span>
            <span class="text-2xl">Today</span>
        </span>

        <span class="flex-grow"></span>

        <img
            v-if="props.renderProfile"
            class="circle rounded-full h-8"
            src="/src/assets/user.png"
            alt="Picture belonging to your profile"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from '@vue/runtime-core'

const props = defineProps<{ renderProfile?: boolean }>()
</script>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: I don't think I will be able to since my team doesn't really want me too and also it works on some devices but not on others.

Comment: Ok. You don't need to share any private code, but an example project that reproduces the problem would suffice. Otherwise, I don't see how we could help with a problem that only you can make happen.

Comment: Sure I'll create an example project and upload it here.

Comment: actually we found a decent work around but thank you for the help